# From SQL to Django without raw method

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm trying to convert SQL Query to Django.
I'm new to Django and I find it hard to do simple things,
here is the SQL query I'm trying to run with Django :

```
SELECT * 
FROM balance_hold bh1
WHERE
   bh1.account_balance = X and
   bh1.hold_id in (
   SELECT hold_id
   FROM balance_hold bh2
   WHERE 
      bh2.transaction_id = bh1.transaction_id and 
      bh2.account_balance = X and
      (
         bh2.release_time = null and hold_type >= 
            (select * from balance_hold bh3 where bh3.transaction_id = bh2.transaction_id and bh3.account_balance = X and bh3.release_time = null)
      ) or 
      (
         bh2.release_time != null and bh2.release_time >= (select release_time from balance_hold bh3 where bh3.transaction_id = bh2.transaction_id and bh3.account_balance = X and bh3.release_time != null)
      ))
```

how do I run this with Django (without using RAW method!)?

Comment: Share your relevant model(s), and explaint *what* you aim to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think attempting to translate an sql query to django ORM is the right way to tackle your issue, regardless you'll need several tools to achieve this.
OR and AND can be written with Q objects (https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#operators-that-return-new-querysets).
The kind of subquery can be achieved with Subquery and OuterRef(https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions).
#column = null can be achieved with __isnull lookup (https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#isnull)

If the syntax of subqueries is not clear, for instance:

```
BalanceHold.objects.filter(account_balance=X, id__in=Subquery(BalanceHold.objects.filter(transaction_id=OuterRef("transaction_id")).values("id")))
```

Will produce:

```
SELECT * FROM "balance_hold" WHERE ("balance_hold"."id" IN (SELECT U0."id" FROM "balance_hold" U0 WHERE U0."transaction_id" = "balance_hold"."transaction_id") AND "balance_hold"."account_balance" = X) ORDER BY "balance_hold"."id" DESC
```